# Github actions- For linter and prettier for angular app in Github

Tags: angular, github, eslint, github-actions, prettier

Please refer the below image. These are the errors I'm getting in Github.

Run wearerequired/lint-action@v1
SHA of last commit is "9c3afb987475ddadfe7f091e26b348bf8421cb69"
Run ESLint
Verifying setup for ESLint…
Verified ESLint setup
Will use ESLint to check the files with extensions js
Linting files in /home/runner/work/angular-app-heroku/angular-app-heroku with ESLint …
Error: ESLint error: Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved

I tried adding yaml file in github actions.

name: Pull Request Validations

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
test:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

```
steps:
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v1
- name: Install node
  uses: actions/setup-node@v1 #this will install Node and npm on Ubuntu
  with:
    node-version: '14.x'
- name: Install dependencies
  run: npm install
- name: Install Angular CLI
  run: npm install -g @angular/cli > /dev/null   
- name: Run linters
  uses: wearerequired/lint-action@v1
  with:
    github_token: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
  # Enable linters
    eslint: true
    prettier: true
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an ESLint error, if don't want to use ESLint checkers, just remove the `step` **Run linters**.

ESlint will verify your code before running and warn you about bad practices, my advice is for you to learn more about eslint and try to run locally, fix the warnings, then push your code to the GitHub.